# the persisting records instructions in the guide don't work for me

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use the instructions find here:
http://emberjs.com/guides/models/persisting-records/

My server receives the json well and creates a record which it then returns properly, but my onSuccess function doesn't get anything usable as a response. It gets this strange object which if I try to pass onto the next route like the instructions say, it errors out saying this:

Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed '' (wrapped in (generated articles.view controller))

Here is my code:
https://github.com/mgenev/Full-Stack-JS-Boilerplate/blob/master/public/ember/controllers/articles_controller.js

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `transitionToArticle` function requires an argument but you're not passing in anything when you're calling it:

```
article.save().then(transitionToArticle).catch(failure);
```